# Python Threading with Serial ports waiting for other thread to complete

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, pyserial

New to Queues and Threads but as I have gotten my program to work and run 2 threads of motors separate from each other, ive noticed that there is still a point in time that one will wait for the other to finish.

I have 2 motors on linear rails. In order to validate their consistency, repeatability, and accuracy it runs a home test. Just giving the motor a fixed number of tests and a position to go to, where it runs back and forth, logs the data and tells me how close we got both in steps and distance. The odd behavior is that one motor is waiting for the other to complete its cycle before starting its next cycle.

My guess is this is a problem with serial reads where my motor is held up waiting for a serial read on one motor and cannot execute the other. Can anyone confirm this or have a work around?

Code for the test, wrapped in a class

```
def home(self):
    DIConf = None
    debugStart = time.time()
    while DIConf != -1:
        self.anyCMD('DI-1')
        while DIConf == None:
            DIConf = self.checkReturn('DI')
        if time.time() - debugStart >= 5:
            print 'DIConf = ' + str(DIConf)
            return 'Homing Timeout'
    self.s.write('SH1H\r')

def homeTest(self, numTests = 30, testPos = 100000):
    if numTests == None:
        numTests = 30
    if testPos == None:
        testPos = 100000
    self.tests = numTests
    self.testingPos = testPos
    self.B = np.zeros((tests, 4))
    for i in range(0, self.tests):
    #    print i
        self.setPos(0)
        self.start = time.time()
        self.gotoPos(self.testingPos)
        self.s.write('WM\r')
        time.sleep(2)
        while self.getPos() < self.testingPos:
            pass
        self.testPosConfirm = self.getPos()
        self.home()#(setHomePos = 1)
        self.s.write('WM\r')
        time.sleep(2)
        self.end = time.time()
        self.backHome = self.getPos()
        self.B[i][0] = self.testPosConfirm
        self.B[i][1] = self.backHome
        self.B[i][2] = (float(self.backHome)/20000) * 3.175
        self.B[i][3] = self.end-self.start
    return self.B
```

and code for the queue/threads

```
import Queue
import threading
a = Queue.Queue()
b = Queue.Queue()
y = motor(DA = 1)
z = motor(DA = 2)

def yQueue(tempY, tempA, cycles = None, defPos = None):
    tempVar = tempY.homeTest(cycles, defPos)
    tempA.put(tempVar)

if 1 == 1:
    thread = threading.Thread(target = yQueue, args = [y, a, 5, 50000])
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target = yQueue, args = [z, b, 5, 600000])
    thread.start()
    thread2.start()
```

As suggested below. Attempted the same thing with Multiprocessing and got similar results.

Code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
p = mp.Process(target = yQueue, args = [y, a, 3, 40000])
p.start()
p.join
p2 = Process(target = yQueue, args = [z, b, 3, 500000])
p2.start()
p2.join
```

Comment: i recommend you to use multiprocessing instead of multithreading, regarding that python cannot multithread a process with just one interpreter, but multiprocessing instantiate multi interpreters to implement parallel tasking (for real)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Although only a quick look into multiprocessing, the running code is having the same effect. Added the multiprocessing code to the main question